# action mailer gem and tlsmail gem not working in heroku after GIT PUSH HEROKU

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using heroku as my host..It was working fine.

Then I installed action_mailer_tls and tlsmail.
Then I comitted it and pushed it heroku..

After that I got error in myapp.heroku.com.
The error is

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- smtp_tls (MissingSourceFile)
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
 from /disk1/home/slugs/154378_e47562d_b59c/mnt/config/initializers/smtp_gmail.rb:3
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:147:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:147:in `load'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/initializer.rb:622:in `load_application_initializers'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `each'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `load_application_initializers'
... 19 levels...
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
 from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
 from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
```

Do I need to push the gems..If so I tried

```
git add .gems
```

It also gives fatal error.

any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `smtp_tls` in your .gems.

Answer (score 1):

Used

```
rake gems:unpack
```

It will unpack the specified gems to vendor/gems

Answer (score 0):

Yes - this is most likely (almost certainly) b/c the default ruby version on heroku is 1.8.6, and TLS support comes natively in 1.8.7.

If you're feeling brave, you can migrate your heroku app to a newer stack (see 'heroku stack' for more info)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Ruby 1.8.7 or greater, you don't need to install smtp_tls gem. It is already present. You just need to enable_starttls_auto in your config/environment.rb file

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:enable_starttls_auto => true,
:address         => 'smtp.gmail.com',
:port            => 587,
:domain          => 'example.com',
:authentication  => :plain,
:user_name       => 'user',
:password        => 'secret'
}
```

or

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :enable_starttls_auto => true,
 :port           => 587,
 :address        => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :domain         => "example.com",
 :user_name      => "user",
 :password       => "secret",
 :authentication => :plain
}
```

please add a comment if you have any doubt related to this.